# Sass watch is detecting changes but not compiling to css

Tags: css, sass, mixins, compass, bourbon

When I run `sass --watch app.sass:app.css` terminal shows that changes have been detected to sass but won't compile to css. I am using Bourbon so all my .scss and .sass files are imported via mixins.

ex.

```
 >>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
 >>> Change detected to: css/2-modules/top-nav.scss
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any errors in `top-nav.scss` or any of the files that `top-nav.scss` might import?

Comment: No errors, actually I have made various changes to other .scss files in the project to test the compiler and it is still only detecting changes made to the .scss files without compiling them.

Comment: check config.rb maybe they're being stored in the wrong dir

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the file you are saving with an `_filename.scss` has been properly imported into the `mainfile.scss`. if you have not imported the `_filename.scss` it will detect a change but not compile.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue! In my case, it was caused by having several `@imports` listed like this:

```
@import 'colors';
@import 'fonts';
@import 'size';
```

When i changed it to this it all started working again:

```
@import 'colors', 'fonts', 'size';
```

Although it should not be needed:
"*Sass imports have the same syntax as CSS imports, except that they allow multiple imports to be separated by commas rather than requiring each one to have its own @import.*" - [sass-lang.com/documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Comment: In my case, it only locates the first one :                                                                       
`SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
@import "../assets/scss/elements/ie", "elements/defaults";`

Answer (score 0):

check for the Config.rb file in your folder.
without it you have to Ctr c every time and pass this command sass --watch scssname:cssname

then You can find your code in css.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all of your partials are being imported into app.scss? I had the same issue, only to realize the partial file  I was modifying (_custom.scss) wasn't actually being imported by the main.scss.

Answer (score 0):

Create **scss** file by correct naming **(make sure there is underscore "_")**

```
_custom.scss
```

Import **_custom.scss** in **main.scss** **(no underscore required)**

```
// main.scss
      @import "custom";
```

Compile the code

> sass --watch main.scss main.css

This will compile the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your style folder create a `file.scss` with `"_"` in the **beginning**.   For example: `_fileName.scss`
2. Import it at the start of your principal scss file. For example:

   ```
   // in **mystyle.scss**   
   do : **@import "fileName"** (without the  underscore )
   ```
3. Run your sass in the terminal. For example:

   ```
   sass mystyle.scss:mystyle.css --watch
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it turns out I didn't include the '-w' at the end of my script, in order for the script to keep watching for changes and compile the sass file.

This is what I mean:
"scripts":
"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"